# Are all tomcat ports needed

Tags: tomcat, configuration, webserver, ports

I am trying to set up a tomcat server to host a webapp and need to deal with some compliance issues. The main one being that only port `8443` should be open and accept only SSL connections and not `8080` or any of the other ports tomcat uses which are spelled out in its default layout as seen below

```
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

What would happen if I were to change the above to something such as this?

```
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Would tomcat still work correctly and just be hosted on port `8443` or would I run into issues with only using port `8443`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't make any difference if you are not using a SSL configuration. The redirect port is used to forward to a SSL port. In other words it will work using only port 8443.

Check the [reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) below:

> redirectPort: If this Connector is supporting non-SSL requests, and a request is
>   received for which a matching  requires SSL
>   transport, Catalina will automatically redirect the request to the
>   port number specified here.

Comment: Well it will only be accepting SSL connections. No non SSL connections will be allowed.

Comment: thanks! Was just not sure with all those ports in there by default if it needed 3 ports or what.

Comment: no, actually you just need one... the 8009 AJP port can be used internally to communicate with apache(I never used it), but by default tomcat has this configuration

Comment: And using the AJP port to communicate with HTTPD is not the recommended way to do because HTTPD has to translate the traffic from http to ajp. I don't know what are the usages of the AJP port nowadays. Side note, if you have HTTPD in front of your Tomcat instance and the connection does not need security between these two, you should have a simple http connector on Tomcat. This way you would have client -> https -> httpd -> http -> tomcat .

Comment: @Johnride Use cases for fronting Tomcat with Apache httpd include load-balancing, multiplexing, oddball authentication schemes, and defense-in-depth. There are certainly others. As for encrypting traffic between httpd and Tomcat, that's a matter of environmental requirements. For instance, if httpd is cloud-hosted and Tomcat is not, perhaps some encryption between the two is in order.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I was wondering what are the use cases of the AJP port, not fronting Tomcat with HTTPD (which should be always done for production environments) or encrypting the communication between HTTPD and Apache (which, as you mention, may be relevant in some situations). The AJP protocol just seems more or less relevant nowadays. I guess that AJP to AJP is faster for java servers than having the Java servers using HTTP when no http client is involved.

Comment: @Johnride I wouldn't say that httpd "should always be done in production environments". It's just a deployment strategy that has certain advantages. Tomcat is fully capable of being a production-quality web server.

Comment: True, I just use it as a strong guideline to centralize all public HTTP traffic through a couple of Apache instances instead of having all applications hosting themselves. Easier to manage and to keep secure.

Comment: @Johnride The AJP protocol offers a few things that HTTP has to hack-together. For example, AJP tunnels information about the web server's state such as TLS information (client certificate, cipher suite, etc.). That information shows up automagically in the right places to match the servlet spec's guarantees about where to find that information. If you use HTTP, all that information goes through the HTTP headers (which you may not want) and you have to enable a Valve to handle all that secure stuff for you.